# Data no ng-Model com input date apresenta erro em AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Boa noite, estou tentando realizar o *CRUD* na minha aplicação, usando `AngularJS` e `WEBService`, quando vou alterar dados de um determinado motorista, envio o `JSON` do mesmo para a `SessionStorage`, na página de alterar, acesso o objeto, bem como seus atributos através do `ng-model` dos inputs.

Quando não se trata de datas, o `input` é preenchido com os dados da `SessionStorage`, porém, quando se trata das datas, o `AngularJS` apresenta o seguinte erro no console:

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt].

Alguém saberia como resolver esse erro? não consegui encontrar respostas até então. Obrigado desde já!

Meu input:

```
<label> Data de validade </label>
<input type="date" ng-model="motorista.data_vencimento" id="codigo_motorista" />
```

Meu método que envia o objeto em formato `JSON` para a `SessionStorage`:

```
$scope.enviarDados = function(motorista){
    $scope.jsonObj = angular.toJson(motorista, false);
    window.sessionStorage.motorista = JSON.stringify(motorista);
    window.location.href = "formAlterarMotorista.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O formato de data que você precisa passar para que o *input* reconheça como um formato de data válido deve ser:

```
YYYY-MM-DD //ano-mes-dia
```

Portanto, você deve formatar a data antes de atribuir ao campo.

Comment: obrigado por responder...como eu poderia converter essa "string data" pra esse formato? Eu faria isso onde? No controller ou no meu HTML?

Comment: o meu json tá vindo assim: {"id":13,"endereco":{"id_endereco":37,"logradouro":"Av taquaritinga","numero":188,"bairro":"Jd América","complemento":"Próximo à Vaz Filho","cep":"14811223","cidade":"Araraquara","estado":"São paulo","pais":"Brasil"},"prestador":{"id":1,"nome_fantasia":"teste","razao_social":"teste"},"codigo":"TESTE","nome":"Matheus Simões Minguini","observacao":"Testando o alterar","rg":"404204065","cpf":"45509939877","emissao_rg":"2017-02-13","orgao_expedidor_rg":"SSP","email":"minguinimatheus@gmail.com","telefone":"1633379410","celular":"16997063747","cnh":"4564564645"{

Answer (score 1):

O que está acontecendo é que o Angular não está reconhecendo a variável `motorista.data_vencimento` como um campo de data válido, para isso ao carregar a variável `motorista` podes tratar o campo assim

`$scope.motorista.data_vencimento = new Date(data_vencimento);`

onde `data_vencimento` é o valor que você possivelmente carrega do webservice.

Comment: sabe porque o `value` funciona com string, mas o `ng-model` não?